# Matlab unique cell combinations

Tags: matlab, list, cell

I have a list as given below:

```
A= {[1 2], [2 1], [2 1 3],[3 4],[4 3]}
```

I need to simplify the matrix. For example, `[3 4]` and `[4 3]` form the same combination, only one of them is enough. Also, `[1 2]` and `[2 1]` is the same combinations, so I should be left with

```
newA= {[1 2],[2 1 3],[3 4]}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) the values and use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
A = {[1 2], [2 1], [2 1 3],[3 4],[4 3]};

tmp = cellfun(@sort, A, 'UniformOutput', false);
tmp = cellfun(@num2str, tmp, 'UniformOutput', false);
[~, idx] = unique(tmp);

newA = A(idx);
```

Note 1 that I've had to make a dummy array of the string equivalent of `A` due to `unique`'s handling of cell arrays. `unique` can only work on cell arrays of strings/character vectors so we have to do a little manipulation to get the desired output.

Note 2 that [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) is almost always slower than the explicit loop, but I've used it here for brevity.

Comment: Good idea, convert to strings! You can maybe combine as `tmp = cellfun(@(x) num2str(sort(x)), A, 'UniformOutput', false)`

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way is probably to sort each vector and use two nested loops as follows:

```
As = cellfun(@sort, A, 'UniformOutput', false); % sort each vector
remove = false(size(A)); % initiallize. Entries to be removed will be marked true
for ii = 1:numel(A)
    for jj = ii+1:numel(A)
        remove(jj) = remove(jj) || isequal(As{jj}, A{ii}); % short-circuit OR
    end
end
result = A(~remove);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
n = cellfun(@numel,A);
C=accumarray(n(:),1:numel(A),[],@(x){num2cell(unique(sort(vertcat(A{x}),2),'rows'),2)});
result = vertcat(C{~cellfun(@isempty,C)})
```

I tested 3 proposed answers with the following data in Octave:

```
A=arrayfun(@(x){randi([1 10],1,randi([1 10000]))},1:50);
```

Here is the result:

```
======NUM2STR=======:
Elapsed time is 1.13129 seconds.
======FOR LOOP=======:
Elapsed time is 0.237398 seconds.
======ACCUMARRAY=======:
Elapsed time is 0.036804 seconds.
```

With the following data:

```
A=arrayfun(@(x){randi([1 3],1,randi([1 5]))},1:500);
```

Result:

```
======NUM2STR=======:
Elapsed time is 0.384026 seconds.
======FOR LOOP=======:
Elapsed time is 10.9931 seconds.
======ACCUMARRAY=======:
Elapsed time is 0.0271118 seconds.
```

[Online Demo](http://rextester.com/KYBG23796)